# Unwrapping an existentially quantified GADT

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, gadt, existential-type

I have a custom value type `Value` labeled by its type `ValType`:

```hs
data ValType
  = Text
  | Bool

data Value (tag :: ValType) where
  T :: Text -> Value 'Text
  B :: Bool -> Value 'Bool
```

and I would like to define a function that unwraps an existentially quantified `Value`, that is it should have the following type signature:

```
data SomeValue = forall tag. SomeValue (Value tag)

unwrap :: SomeValue -> Maybe (Value tag)
```

I can define unwrap for `'Bool` and `'Text` separately, but how do I define a polymorphic `unwrap`?

Comment: One possible workaround is to use an open union, but I'm still curious whether this can be done for GADT.

Comment: basically, how do I pattern match on promoted types? I think you can do that at type-level with type families but how do you do that at the term level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really can't avoid a typeclass or equivalent here. `unwrap`, as you've written its type, has no way to know *which* tag it's looking for, because types are erased. An idiomatic approach uses the singleton pattern.

```hs
data SValType v where
  SText :: SValType 'Text
  SBool :: SValType 'Bool

class KnownValType (v :: ValType) where
  knownValType :: SValType v
instance KnownValType 'Text where
  knownValType = SText
instance KnownValType 'Bool where
  knownValType = SBool

unwrap :: forall tag. KnownValType tag => SomeValue -> Maybe (Value tag)
unwrap (SomeValue v) = case knownValType @tag of
  SText
    | T _ <- v -> Just v
    | otherwise -> Nothing
  SBool
    | B _ <- v -> Just v
    | otherwise -> Nothing
```

Unlike the `IsType` class of your own answer, `KnownValType` lets you get type information as well as a value tag out of a pattern match. So you can use it much more generally for handling these types.

For cases where your `typeOf` is sufficient, we can write it with no trouble:

```
 typeOf :: KnownValType a => Proxy a -> ValType
 typeOf (_ :: Proxy a) = case knownValType @a of
   SBool -> Bool
   SText -> Text
```

Comment: For this specific example, `unwrap :: SomeValue -> Either (Value 'Text) (Value 'Bool)` also looks appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

As yet another alternative, using `Typeable` and `cast` makes for a pretty concise solution.  You still have to carry around a dictionary, but you don't have to build it yourself:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, GADTs,
    KindSignatures, StandaloneDeriving, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Typeable

data ValType
  = Text
  | Bool

data Value (tag :: ValType) where
  T :: Text -> Value 'Text
  B :: Bool -> Value 'Bool
deriving instance Show (Value 'Text)
deriving instance Show (Value 'Bool)

data SomeValue = forall tag. SomeValue (Value tag)

unwrap :: (Typeable tag) => SomeValue -> Maybe (Value tag)
unwrap (SomeValue (T t)) = cast (T t)
unwrap (SomeValue (B b)) = cast (B b)

main = do
  print (unwrap (SomeValue (T "foo")) :: Maybe (Value 'Text))
  print (unwrap (SomeValue (T "foo")) :: Maybe (Value 'Bool))
```

Comment: `Typeable` seems like overkill for a closed universe.

Comment: I guess, but so does writing a polymorphic `unwrap`.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution, defined a typeclass to reify types of kind `ValType` back to terms:

```hs
class IsType a where
  typeOf :: Proxy a -> ValType

instance IsType 'Text where
  typeOf _ = Text

instance IsType 'Bool where
  typeOf _ = Bool

unwarp :: IsType tag => SomeValue -> Maybe (Value tag)
unwarp (SomeValue v) =
  case typeOf (Proxy @tag) of
    Bool ->
      case v of
        B _ -> Just v
        _ -> Nothing
    Text ->
      case v of
        T _ -> Just v
        _ -> Nothing
```

But I'll have to carry around that typeclass dictionary which is not very elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be acceptable?

```
data SomeValue = forall tag. (Typeable tag) => SomeValue (Value tag)

unwrap :: (Typeable tag) => SomeValue -> Maybe (Value tag)
unwrap (SomeValue t) = cast t
```

The "cast general type to `Maybe` specific type" pattern is pretty much what `Typeable` is for.